# bind-9.11.2 got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure

Tags: networking, security, dns

I administer a couple of networks with 10-30 machines, and I run a `bind` nameserver to provide DNS resolution to my clients (instead of forwarding to Comcast or Google -- I don't care to advertise my users' internet activity that way).  My nameserver is authoritative for some local things, and it does full from-root resolution of everything else.  This mostly works correctly, but even after a fresh restart, it doesn't take long for bind to start logging `got insecure response; parent indicates it should be secure` errors.  I believe these occur when a brand-new name is resolved, when my copy of `bind` starts resolving from `.com` or `.org` or whatever.

I haven't yet dug into the current DNS protocol, or started `tcpdump` sniffing; I hope that somebody will be able to say "your timebase is off" or something similar that will save me from the deep DNS dive.  (I have NTP running, and I believe my system times are close enough that that's not the problem.)

Is there a common problem that affects small sites running a recursing nameserver like this?  Or is there a good tool for running in parallel to `bind` that can help me figure out why `bind` is complaining?  Note that even when some names won't resolve, I believe others do.  For example, I might have a problem with `foo.bar.com.` that is reported as `validating .com/SOA: got insecure response`, but `gibble.gobble.com` resolves OK.  (My `bind` is running on a self-built OpenWRT router, so it's somewhat inconvenient to build new versions of tools, but if I have to re-build and re-install a new system, I could do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that the domain you are looking at is DNSSEC-enabled (i.e. the parent domain has a DS record pointing to the child, meaning that records in the child should be signed), but either the response didn't come with a DNSSEC signature (misconfiguration on the domain) or your nameserver failed to interpret the DNSSEC signature (perhaps the signature generated with a crypto algorithm that your DNS server can't handle). Without a specific example of a domain that failed to resolve, we can't no which.

You could turn off DNSSEC validation which will certainly stop the errors (and name-resolution) failures, but security-wise that's not a great idea. If you never lock the front door of your house, you will never find yourself locked out either ;-)  If the cause of the errors is DNSSEC misconfiguration on the domain, there is obviously not much you can do about it (I don't think BIND provides a way to selectively ignore DNSSEC errors on a per-domain basis, even if you wanted to). If the problem is an unsupported crypto algorithm in your version of BIND, then an update to BIND might be the only fix.